# Keeping busy/Increasing Coding Chops on slow work days

Tags: android

So I've been doing a lot of app development, and code maintenance at work.  I'm an android developer, though I do some other stuff around the office occasionally.  The last few weeks we've had a shortage of tickets for me to work on, and the ones I've gotten I've pounded out and been bored for several hours after.

I'm looking for some good activities, guides, projects etc.. that I can work on during these down times to keep my android skills sharp.  I've been reading up on optimization, security, design and implementation strategies and some other fun stuff.

I'm looking for short projects - 1-3 hours long, which will teach me something meaningful about the platform, reveal some hidden aspect I didn't understand, or otherwise just be really cool so I can be like - "yea boss, I'm a baller".   Beyond that - really well implemented code would be cool too, I like looking at other peoples stuff and as I'm doing a lot of maintenance programming the ability to quickly aclimate with code is something I'm trying to work on.

Thanks guys,

Comment: I think this is an interesting question but I think that it is not on-topic for SO. My advice though for one exercise is look for (complex) UI implementation is released applications and attempt to re-create them.

Comment: No offense, but shouldn't you be asking your boss what to do during slow work days?

Comment: @nomin none taken, I do but there is definitely some intermittent downtime.  Just trying to increase my value during those down times.

Comment: @tim - yea I wasn't sure if it was ontopic enough or not, but I figured it was worth a go...

Comment: @NominSim I can't speak for Nathaniel, but I can say that personally my boss would have no clue as to what types of specific things to to have me sharpen my skills at.

Comment: @Tim My point wasn't that so much as; maybe if his boss knew that he had this much free time during the day he would have more work to give him to do. Most companies I am sure would rather the employee be doing work (even menial) that produces something tangible for the company rather than them improving their own skill set. (Just a point of fact, I don't necessarily agree with that viewpoint.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done like this:

1) You are amazed by some application or some part of some application similar to how one gets amazed by seeing some beautiful thing

2) Being a programmer you, however, have an advantage of analyzing your amazement in terms of programming and are able then to formulate for yourself a quest something like 'how can I achieve such an amazing `OK Button` (or perhaps `Cancel Button`)

3) You then start working on achieving that same `Ok` (or `perhaps Cancel`) button in your small test project

4) You then stuck

Answer (score 3):

How about using your 'down time' answering questions on **StackOverflow**. I find it a delightful diversion after a gruelling day in the "Android Swamp Mines (tm)" ;-)

Seriously though, there are a lot of questions that are better answered if you create a small test program to test the user's problem and your answer. The community also gets better quality answers.

Comment: Alas! Answering questions on SO is not related to polishing programming skills at all. I don't think it's even related to programming at all.

Comment: @Alex I disagree. I've learned quite a lot by doing as David suggests (actually researching to answer the question). If you only answer questions based on what you already know, then no, you won't improve.

Comment: I like this one a lot actually.  Hadn't thought about it.  Baring something brilliant I'll probably accept it!